# How can someone exercise their right to a copy of their data from a company?

Tags: privacy, european-union, civil-law, data-protection, utah

I’m familiar with [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/); in Utah it appears the analogous law is the [Consumer Protection Act](https://le.utah.gov/%7E2022/bills/static/SB0227.html). In principle, I thought that GDPR gives anyone the right to request a copy of the data a company has about them. Since becoming more aware of this, I have also become aware of how it does not seem particularly actionable to actually do so. For example, I recently was unable to download my data from Facebook, twice.

Is there actually any law that people have the right to know what data a company has on them? If there is one, is it even being effectively enforced? Are laws like GDPR and the CPA all for show? Are the consumer rights actually consistently exercisable?

Comment: I edited the question to remove unnecessary detail and to make it more generic. I would suggest keeping future questions to just parts that ask about the law. In particular, questions which describe a specific scenario you are experiencing in real life are likely to be closed as they are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

The starting point is to make a written request for a copy of your data to the data controller under [Article 12(3)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-3-article-12/) and [15(1)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-3-article-15/) of the UK GDPR. There is no need to phrase your request in a particular way or to make any reference to the law, as long as you are clear about what data you are asking for. The data controller must reply without undue delay, pursuant to Article 12(3), with an upper time limit of 1 month. For a complex request they can take up to 3 months, but they must notify you of the delay within 1 month. They can refuse to provide the data, but only if the request is "manifestly unfounded or excessive". For a first-time request this is unlikely to be applicable. If it is reasonable to do so in the circumstances, the data controller can ask you to prove your identity under Article 12(6) in which case the clock is paused while they await your response.

If they ultimately do not respond within the deadline, or they respond and fail or refuse to disclose the data, you have two options.

The first option is to complain to your country's data protection Commissioner (the [ICO](https://ico.org.uk/make-a-complaint/) in E&W). This right is derived from [Article 77](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-77/). The Commissioner has the power to order the data controller to comply with your request, under [Article 58(2)(c)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-6-article-58/). They can also order the data controller to pay you compensation if you have suffered "material or non-material damage" under [Article 82(1)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-82/), and can issue a fine under [Article 84(2)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-84/) and [83(6)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-83/) of up to £17,500,000 or 4% of annual turnover, whichever is higher.

The second option is to seek a compliance order in the County Court, under [Article 79(1)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-79/) and [Section 167 of the Data Protection Act 2018](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/12/section/167). The Court also has the power to award compensation under [Section 168](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/12/section/168).

Complaining to the ICO is free and without any risk. If you apply for a compliance order you will have to pay a court fee and potentially risk paying the other side's costs if you lose. If you win you will almost certainly be able to recover the court fee from the defendant. Complaining to the ICO does not prevent you from subsequently applying for a compliance order if you aren't happy with the outcome. For this reason, starting with an ICO complaint is the recommended option unless you require your data urgently.

> Are laws like GDPR and the CPA all for show? Are the consumer rights
> actually consistently exercisable?

The powers of the ICO and the courts under the GDPR are very real and can have very serious consequences for non-compliant data controllers. Most large companies have a dedicated process for making data requests (informally known as "subject access requests"). For those that don't, they are likely to start paying attention if you make an ICO complaint, or issue a Country Court claim.

The UK GDPR is very similar to the GDPR. The latter is applicable throughout the EU and confers equivalent rights and enforcement mechanisms.